# I can't change the Secure Boot mode to enabled "Failed to delete Secure Boot state"?

Tags: boot, uefi, security, secure-boot, firmware

I have Ubuntu 21.10. Secure Boot is showen as enabled, in the BIOS of the Computer, but as I used the sudo mokutil --sb-state to check the status it says "SecureBoot disabled".
Then I used sudo mokutil --enable-validation to change it in the MOK Menu, but after I confirmed to enable Secure Boot, I get the Message "Failed to delete Secure Boot state".

Outputs of SecureBoot and SetupMode:

```
 hexdump -C /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/SecureBoot-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c 
00000000  06 00 00 00 00  

 hexdump -C /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/SetupMode-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
00000000  06 00 00 00 00
```

Why is this happening? My motherboard is Asus VIII hero and the firmware is the latest version.

Comment: The same way some firmwares don't allow changes made by `efibootmgr`, it seems your doesn't allow enabling/disabling Secure Boot from `mokutil`. Please use the UEFI settings for that.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Oh so my secure boot is actually on? Because it is turned on in Bios settings at least. If so, then why does mokutil says that my secure boot is off?